# Retrieve two strings from one

Tags: php

I need to get two strings from one.

```
$string = "Service rating : good<br/>Product : good";
```

should return:

```
$service = 'good';
$product = 'good';
```

and

```
$string = "Service rating : Excellent service!<br/>Product : Outstanding product - this is the second scarf I've ordered.";
```

should return:

```
$service = 'Excellent service!';
$product = 'Outstanding product - this is the second scarf I've ordered.';
```

How can I best achieve this?

Comment: Have you tried something ?

Comment: I've tried to use a preg_match but couldn't work it out. I am thinking that I should somehow break it at the <br/>, then strip the "Service rating : " and "<br/>Product : " from the two strings, leaving the actual useful stuff. I just don't know how to do that.

Comment: i gave an example of how to do this with preg_match, did you try it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can separate the string using the `explode` function 2 times. First - to separate the service from product using the tag `<br/>` in the middle. 
The second use will get the corresponding status  - using explode with the string **" : "**

Here is the code

```
<?php
$input = "Service rating : good<br/>Product : good";
list($service, $product) = explode('<br/>', $input);

$service = explode(' : ', $service);
$product = explode(' : ', $product);
echo $service[1];
echo "<br>";
echo $product[1];
?>
```

Comment: Thank you, this is a nice approach.

Answer (score 0):

```
$a = explode("<br/>", $string);
```

will provide you with an array with two values: the strings you ask for.

Then:

```
echo $a[0];
echo $a[1];
```

will print the two strings.

Or use `list` to assign those values to your requested variables:

```
list($service, $product) = explode("<br/>", $string);
```

Then, as bladerz suggests, repeat the explode with `' : '` for getting the ratings for service and product.

Answer (score 0):

You could use regular expressions for your solution. I give an example:

```
$string = "Service rating : good<br/>Product : good";
$re = '/^.*\:\s*(?:(?<service>[\w\s]+)\<br\/>).*\:\s*(?<product>[\w\s]+)$/';

if (preg_match($re, $string, $matches))
{
    $service = $matches['service'];
    $product = $matches['product'];
}

var_dump($service, $product);
```

Explanation of the used expression:

- skip everything from beginning until 1st `:`
- extract `service` match delimited by `<br/>`
- skip everything until 2nd `:`
- extract `product` match (until end of string)

You can play around with it here: https://regex101.com/r/vH4aZ9/2

Answer (score 0):

Just an alternative using [preg_match_all()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php):

Basically:

- `([a-zA-Z\s]+) : ([a-zA-Z\s-\']+)` Search for a group of words with the allowed chars inside the square brackets, with a semicolon between them.

You can then apply your logic to handle the resulting array.

---

```
$string1 = "Service rating : good<br/>Product : good";

$string2 = "Service rating : Excellent service!<br/>Product : Outstanding product - this is the second scarf I've ordered.";


function getRate($string) {
    preg_match_all('#([a-zA-Z\s]+?) : ([a-zA-Z\s-\']+)#', $string, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);

    return $matches ?: false;
}

var_dump(getRate($string1));


var_dump(getRate($string2));
```